# How to italicize "et al." in citation call-out when using the agsm bibliography style and natbib citation management package

Tags: bibtex, natbib, italic, harvard-style

I read through several questions raised before, but couldn't find a direct solution. I'm using **overleaf online latex editor** to compile my .tex file. I handle a separate .bib file for references. I need my document to be referenced in Harvard (aka "authoryear") style, with et. al. in italics.

Here's the partial code of my main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

I want to cite this \citep{auth} here.

\bibliographystyle{agsm} % 'agsm' is part of 'harvard' package
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

In the ref.bib` file I has the following:

```
@article{auth,
  title = {xxx},
  year = {2000},
  author = {aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd}
}
```

What I want here is (aaa *et al.* 2000) instead of (aaa et al. 2000).
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related: you should use curly `{}` when loading `natbib`: `\usepackage{natbib}`

Comment: That's a typo. Let me edit. Thanks for pointing out. I still have the same issue.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting, as it's irrelevant whether you use Overleaf or some other (non-online) TeX distribution.

Comment: Off-topic: `author = {aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd}` cannot possibly lead to a good outcome. It should be `author = {aaa and bbb and ccc and ddd}`.

Comment: If you can't find the file `agsm.bst` in the Overleaf distribution, you may download it from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/agsm.bst.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the support. Yes I read through the question which has previously been asked, and although it is exactly the same as my question, I did not find the perfect solution which I was looking for. One of the problems was that, I couldn't find ```agsm.bst``` in overleaf plus I got no clue on it. I'll try to use the link you suggested.

Comment: All good! I got my task done. Many thanks